# How to generate leaflet control from database

Tags: leaflet

I wish to generate a custom dropdown filter, based on categories from a database.
How is this achieved?

In my example, this is (poorly) implemented with some hard coding and duplication.

```
var serviceOverlays = [
    {name:"Cardiology", value:"cardiology"},
    {name:"Opthamology", value:"opthamology"}
];

var oSelect = L.control({position : 'topright'});
oSelect.onAdd = function (map) {
    var overlayParent = document.getElementById('new-parent'); // overlays div 
    var node = L.DomUtil.create('select', 'leaflet-control');
    node.innerHTML = '<option value="cardiologist">Cardioligist</option><option value="opthamology">Opthamology</option>';

    overlayParent.appendChild(node);
    L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(node);
    L.DomEvent.on(node,'change',function(e){
        var select = e.target;
        for(var name in serviceOverlays){
            serviceOverlays[name].removeFrom(map);
            }
            serviceOverlays[select.value].addTo(map);
   });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4xn53by/)

Answer (score 1):

I created a Control for you:

```
L.Control.Select = L.Control.extend({
    options: {
        position : 'topright'
    },
    initialize(layers,options) {
        L.setOptions(this,options);
        this.layers = layers;
    },
    onAdd(map) {
        this.overlayParent = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control select-control');
        this.node = L.DomUtil.create('select', 'leaflet-control',this.overlayParent);
        L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(this.node);

        this.updateSelectOptions();

        L.DomEvent.on(this.node,'change',(e)=>{
            var select = e.target;
            for(var value in this.layers){
                this.layers[value].layer.removeFrom(map);
            }
            this.layers[select.value].layer.addTo(map);
       });
        return this.overlayParent;
    },
    updateSelectOptions(){
        var options = "";
        if(this.layers){
          for(var value in this.layers){
              var layer = this.layers[value];
              options += '<option value="'+value+'">'+layer.name+'</option>';
          }
        }
        this.node.innerHTML = options;
    },
    changeLayerData(layers){
        this.layers = layers;
        this.updateSelectOptions();
    }
});

var oSelect = new L.Control.Select(serviceOverlays,{position : 'topright'}).addTo(map);
```

The data structure have to be:

```
var serviceOverlays = {
                "cardiology": {name:"Cardiology", layer: cities},
                "opthamology": {name:"Opthamology", layer: badCities}
        };
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/1rLntbo5/

You can also change the data dynamicl< with `oSelect.changeLayerData(serviceOverlays2)`

Comment: Thats great, but, how do I populate the serviceOverlays variable, from a database (API end-point)?

Comment: Add to your server a php file which reads out the data from the database and return this as a JSON String. Then you can call from your JS the php file and reads out the json and  then create the `serviceOverlays`out of the json